# Complicated Find row in duplicate show which column A or B or C

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Could you please help me for below formula little bit complicated
Problem is
In a sheet I have three column A,B,C any one column amount if it is same in D column need to highlight and show which column A or B orC..
Example

```
A B C D amount in each row
4 5 7 4 please highlight bez a and d match
```

Next example
5 3 6 2 should not highlight show error msg

In above case D is matching same number with AorBorC
Please help me this logic formula

Formula

`=If(countif(A1:d4)=1, "duplicate","unique")`

working fine but is there any possibility to show which cell column A or B or C  ... If duplicate which column need to mention

Much appreciated for this complicated formula am not sure whether it required VBA here

Comment: Do you want it to say the column letter, or do you want to highlight the matching cells with a colour? If the latter, then you can use conditional formatting to do that. More on that can be found here: https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html

Comment: Am looking for column letter.... If D column match With any A or B or C column ... Case 1 A and B May match with D column that time need to show letter A and B ... Like whichever column match need to show column letter ( A,B,C rare situation Aand B Also match with D ) A B C all together match with D column that time need to show ABC letter as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question mentions "Highlight", so here's that part of the solution. Select your first 3 columns of data (A1:C6 in my case). Then go to Conditional Formatting in the Home Tab. Create New Rule, using a Formula to determine which cells to format.

Here's the formula:

```
     =A1=$D1
```

[image]

Change the format fill to your color of choice. Click OK.

[image]

**EDIT** - Adding the last piece here...

Lastly, to display which column(s) match column D value, you could use a formula such as this.

Cell E1 Formula:

```
    =CONCAT(IF(A1=D1,"A",""),IF(B1=D1,"B",""),IF(C1=D1,"C",""))
```

Drag it down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`XLOOKUP` unlike `VLOOKUP` returns a reference to the cell and not just the value of the cell.

With this in mind `=XLOOKUP(D2,A2:C2,A2:C2,NA())` will return the value if it exists as well as the reference.

If we wrap the *Return Array* with the `Column` function it will return the column number.
`=XLOOKUP(D2,A2:C2,COLUMN(A2:C2),NA())`

Add the `ADDRESS` function to return the cell address (this will return the address on row 1)
`=XLOOKUP(D2,A2:C2,ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A2:C2),4),NA())`

Now substitute the 1 in the cell address with a blank:
`=SUBSTITUTE(XLOOKUP(D2,A2:C2,ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A2:C2),4),NA()),"1","")`

[image]

Comment: Not sure why @JoeJ deleted his answer - looks like it works if you add a 0 for the _Match Type_ and would work in versions prior to 365.